# How to make pandas groupby().count() sum values rather than rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am aware that size() is the one that count rows, and count() *should* be counting values. However, that isn't happening. When I compare the .count() vs .size(), I get the same result, when they should be greatly different. My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TEST1.csv",sep=';')

df.columns = ['Time','Type','Value','Size','Buyer']

df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'])
df['Size'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Size'])

n_of_buyers = df.groupby("Buyer")["Size"].count()
print(n_of_buyers)
```

I thought that by having the `df['Size'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Size'])` I shouldn't have this issue, and yet...

Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Are you actually looking for `sum` Rather than `count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use is [GroupBy.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)